# VueJS data object is 2 data objects combined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have this basic VUE.js page, but I want variable C to be a composite of variable A and B together.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    fullname: firstname + lastname
  }
})
```

so I can use it in a `<input type="text" v-model="fullname">` and it will contain the values of firstname and lastname.

firstname and lastname will be binded to 2 other inputs as follows:

```
<label>Insert your first name:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="firstname">
<label>Insert your last name:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="lastname">
```

so the fullname variable will be a dynamically binded firstname + lastname variable.

I've tried several things but I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: Do you want the fullname to be an input?

Comment: Check: [Computed Properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: The reason I ask is because typically you will do this with a computed property, but if you bind it to an `input` what do you expect to happen when the user changes the fullname input. Do you expect the value to be split out into first name and last name and how do you expect to accomplish that? By spaces? Etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
  },
  computed: {
    fullname: function(){
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a property that is dependent on other properties.
So use computed.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
  },
  computed: {
    fullname: function () { 
      return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}` 
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this exact example [in the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

Working code snippet, with some additional checks, so the `fullname` is editable too:

```js
 var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      firstname: 'Foo',
      lastname: 'Bar'
    },
    computed: {
      fullname: {
        // getter
        get: function () {
          return this.lastname ? this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname : this.firstname
        },
        // setter
        set: function (newValue) {
          if (newValue.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
              var names = newValue.split(' ')
              this.firstname = names[0]
              this.lastname = names[1] ? names[1] : ''
          } else {
              this.firstname = newValue
          }
        }
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<label>Insert your first name:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="firstname">
<label>Insert your last name:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="lastname">
<label>Insert your full name:</label>
<input type="text" v-model="fullname">
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Kevdev that's exactly what you asked for. `<input type="text" v-model="fullname">` is in your question…